# Why stresses develop during non-uniform heating and not during uniform?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-analysis, thermal-expansion

Consider a block of dimensions $l, b, h$ kept on a frictionless surface, initially at some uniform temperature $ T_i $. Assume the material to be homogeneous and isotropic.

When the block is heated uniformly there are no stresses developed in the block because the block is not restrained to move. It can expand in all directions freely.

When the block is heated non uniformly, my textbook says there will be stresses developed. Why is that so? The block is still not restrained to move.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagin the block is heated on the bottom and has expanded to $l+\delta l$, but this expansion tries to expand the top part along with it.

So the will be some strain between the hot lower part and the cold top part which will cause stress until the whole block is at temperature $T_i+\delta i$

Some years ago I had to supervise a steel frame structure. They had stacked steel columns on the site where they would be exposed to the direct sun at around 11 am daily.

When the sun hit the stack of columns the top ones would expand and move the lower rows with them creating a loud screeching sound. As the project progressed and lower-level columns were lifted by the crane, some were damaged and had crushed spots on the flanges due to the thermal action of the top layer.

Comment: Beautiful Answer.